# Is there a way to run python script in a Core-Network emulator?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I am using Core-Network Emulator (just like packet tracer) in an Ubuntu system to connect a network of systems. I intend running some python scripts on any of the systems but I can't access the text file (.py file) on the local ubuntu machine from the emulator. I tried running the script directly inside the command prompt of the systems on the emulator yet I kept having this error `No module named scapy.all`. Again, I tried using `os.sys.path.append('....')`, but it's still showing error too. Can anyone help please?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

try using the full path name (e.g., python3 /user/john/test/script.py) - assuming appropriate permissions and python modules are in place.